ERESOLVE could not resolve While resolving: react-thunk@1.0.0
I am building my project using EAS and the build is failing with this error:
npm ERR! While resolving: react-thunk@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.9
npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.9" from react-native-paper@5.12.5

I am currently using react@18.1.0
have tried installing using --legacy-peer-deps and it does not change this error
